# How can i check if a plugin is enabled on grav cms / twig if plugin contain dash inside its name?

Tags: php, twig, grav

I build a theme for Grav cms and i need to check if a plugin is enabled or not using the code below inside my twig template:

```
{% if config.plugins.star-ratings.enabled %}
//Then do this and that...
{% endif %}
```

The problem is that this code gives error because there is the dash inside the plugin name:

```
star-ratings
```

Which would be the right syntax in twig? I also tried:

```
{% if config.plugins.["star-ratings"].enabled %}
```

but still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried with `{% if config.plugins["star-ratings"].enabled %}`?

Comment: Yes i already mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Notice the missing dot in front of the square brackets

Comment: @Teneff i missed that dot sorry,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried **(without the dot)**:

```
{% if config.plugins["star-ratings"].enabled %}
    enabled
{% else %}
    disabled
{% endif %}
```

[working example](https://twigfiddle.com/33yf9s)

Comment: Your solution works absolutely perfect. Selecting it as the best answer in the next 6 minutes ;)